# If a coin is selected, what is the probability that is was the 5th coin?

Tags: probability

> We have $10$ coins such that if the ith coin is flipped, it will
> probability of heads of $\frac{i}{10}$ where $i=1,..,10$. We select a
> coin at random, flip it, and we obtain heads. What is the probability
> that it was the fifth coin??

### Attempt

Call A event that the selected coin was the 5th and $B$ event that the coin showed heads after flip. We want to find $P(A \mid B)$. We have

$$ P(A \mid B) = \frac{ P(B \mid A) P(A) }{P(B \mid A) P(A) + P(B \mid A^c) P(A^c) } $$

Notice that $P(B \mid A) = \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(A) = \frac{1}{10}$. Similarly, $P(A^c) = \frac{9}{10}$. Now,

$$ P(B \mid A^c) = ....$$

If we condition on the event that the coin selected wasnt the fifth coin,  then it must have been one of the other 9th remaining? I get stuck on evaluating this probability. any hints? am I on the right direction?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.  Instead of 2 cases $A$ and $A^c$, you have ten cases, so the denominator should be $\sum_i P(B|A_i)P(A_i)$

Comment: Note that $P(B|A)=P(B|A_5)=\frac{5}{10}$. And in general: $P(B|A_i)=\frac{i}{10}$. At the denominator you must have $P(B)=\sum_i P(A_i)P(B|A_i)$.

Comment: Well, the denominator is correct as it is, it's just unnecessarily complicated to separate out the $A$ case in the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, your work so far is correct, but the denominator will be easier to evaluate if you sum over all $10$ cases instead of separating out the case $i=5$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf P(I=5\mid B)
&=&
\frac{\mathsf P(B\mid I=5)\mathsf P(I=5)}{\mathsf P(B)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathsf P(B\mid I=5)\mathsf P(I=5)}{\sum_i\mathsf P(B\mid I=i)\mathsf P(I=i)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac1{10}}{\sum_i\frac1{10}\cdot\frac i{10}}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

The sum in the denominator is just the average of the probabilities $\frac i{10}$, which is $\frac12\left(\frac1{10}+\frac{10}{10}\right)=\frac{11}{20}$, so

$$
\mathsf P(I=5\mid B)=\frac{\frac1{20}}{\frac{11}{20}}=\frac1{11}\;.
$$

You could obtain the result more easily by using symmetry: Add another coin with $i=0$. Then $P(B)=\frac12$ by symmetry, and $P(I=5\mid B)=\frac1{11}$ by symmetry. (By symmetry, the probability is the same whether you condition on heads or tails, and the average of those two equal conditional probabilities is the unconditional probability of picking $i=5$, which is $\frac1{11}$.) Now note that if you observe heads, you can exclude the possibility that the coin with $i=0$ was picked, so the problem reduces to your problem without the $i=0$ coin; hence the answer to your problem is also $\frac1{11}$.